# Create enum list of stored images

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an 'Images' folder in the solution explorer. Can I create an enum list of all the images (& their paths). I want to add that list to a dropdown. For now I am doing this explicitly:

```
private enum bgImages
    {
        BlueArt,GreenArt,StripeArt
    }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string[] Backgrounds = Enum.GetNames(typeof(bgImages));
      ddlBackground.DataSource = Backgrounds;
      ddlBackground.DataBind();
    }

 //..........
 pnlImage.BackImageUrl="~/Images/"+ddlBackground.SelectedItem.Text+".jpg";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Server.MapPath` with `Directory.GetFiles` to load the image names as below

```
ddlBackground.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), "*.jpg")
                 .Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToList();
```

you can directly bind it to control.

Answer (score 0):

Well, an enum has to be ready at compile time, so no.

What you can do however is use the Directory class to get all images in a folder.

```
Directory.GetFiles("[MyImagesPath]","*.jpg");
```

Will return the path of all files with the .jpg extension in the folder.

[More information can be found here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/directory-getfiles)